# Styles often occur in the same combination: Creating a single class or combining elements?

Tags: html, css, coding-style, stylesheet

In one of my recent projects, I noticed that certain styles occur in the same combination repeatedly. According to the DRY principle, I should combine these styles. Regarding a good CSS style, what option is better/the best?

**Option 1**
Creating a class that contains these styles and simply add it in the HTML to the according elements.

Example

In the HTML:

```
<a href='#' class="myClass">Link</a>
```

or

```
<ul class="myClass">
  <li>Item</li>
<ul>
```

In the CSS:

```
.myClass {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: grey;
}
```

**Option 2**
Simply combining all elements that need that style in my CSS, like in the following example.

```
a,
ul {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.myClass {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: grey;
}
```

is best ...

```
.myclass {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: grey;
}
```

is even better **(lower-case)**

This way, the DOM engine will get to the element without having to stack across all a and all ul tags in your document.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your logic. You say, "the DOM engine will get to the element without having to stack across all `a` and all `ul` tags in your document." But as I understand the question, he would be adding `myClass` to all `a` and `ul` tags to get them to have the the style settings he wants common to them, so the engine will be doing that either way. Also, I like `camelCasing` :-).

Comment: @ScottS That is correct, I would apply that class to all elements that need that style. Any why is camel case not good for CSS? Actually I thought thats just a matter of taste/convention. I know guys that would write it like `.my-class`...

Comment: h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
}
H1 {
  color: red;
}

The first rule will apply to all level-one headings in HTML (even if the tags are written as <H1>…</H1> in HTML) and XHTML.

The second rule will apply to all level-one headings in HTML, even if the tags are written as <h1>…</h1>. It won’t apply to any heading element in an XHTML document.

Comment: camelCasing for .css class is not acceptable in Xhtml. So, in order to transport your .css style sheets from a html or html5  to  xhtml doctype .. it will be preferable to avoid the situation of having to 'rewrite' your styles. For your information : xhtml is lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

I often encounter the same problem and have learned to go for **Option 2**.

First, you need to ask yourself why both styles are connected: are the two elements you're styling meant to *always* be styled the same way **or** is is just a coincidence that they're styled the same?

For example, if you decide that your links shouldn't be grey anymore, but blue, will you be ok to have your ul list be blue as well? What I mean is: are the links *and* the list related? Do they have to look always the same? Or it just *happens*, in this particular situation, that they're the same?

Also, you need to beware of the **name** of your class.

- If you call it something like `.boldGrey`, you're doing it wrong because your class name is desribing the style, not the content.
- If you call it something like `.secondary`, you're doing it well, because you're describing the content, not the style. In that case, using Option 1 *can* be ok.

But in the end, **I always go for Option 2**. Although you connect the same style to multiple elements, it's still easy to modify it afterwards, if you change your mind. I usually put at the top of my CSS (just below the reset) a list of elements that share the same properties. Then, I add specific styles for each element.

Example from my website:

```
time, code, figcaption {
  background:#f5f5f5;
  border:1px solid #e9e9e9;
  border-radius:2px;
  color:#93a1a1;
  font-size:11px;
  padding:0 4px 1px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Then, below, I have for example some additional styling for `code`:

```
code {
  font-size:12px;
  position:relative;
  top:-2px;
}
```

While I was styling these 3 elements, I noticed that I wanted them to look the same. But not *exactly* the same. So I regrouped everything they had in *common*, and then specified what they had in *particular*.

Could I have used a single class for that? Maybe. But how would I have called it? .greySmallBordered? .littleBlocks? .tagLooking? It's **really** hard to come up with a name that *only* describes the content and not the styling.

So I usually list multiple elements in my selector because:

- it's the best way to keep the content in the HTML seperated from the styling in the CSS
- it helps specifying additional styling for each element

Comment: Funny, the naming problem is actually the reason that made me think about the two options. Glad to hear that I am not alone ;-) But as you can see, there is still some disagreement which option is the best.